# ActionView::Template::Error: Invalid CSS syntax with "select-bg-img" selector and "background-image" property in Rails application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, assets, precompile

I'm encountering an error in my Rails application related to an invalid CSS syntax. The error message I receive is:

arduino

ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after '...select-bg-img: ': expected '}', was 'url("data:image..."'):

This error seems to be related to the select-bg-img selector and the background-image property. I have checked the CSS code, but I'm unable to identify the issue causing this error.

Here is an example of the relevant CSS code:

css

```css
.select-bg-img {
  background-image: url("path/to/image.jpg");
}
```

I have made sure that the opening and closing curly braces are balanced and that the URL value inside the url() function is valid and properly closed with a closing parenthesis.

Can anyone help me identify what could be causing this error and suggest a possible solution? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: your css looks fine. Perhaps the same class/attribute has a duplicate definition in the same file or another css file?

Comment: And also i want to mention this error is showing it for Bootstrap 5

Comment: It is resolved now. After installing sassc-rails gem.